# What to use in replacement of return boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i've applied validation to my form through jquery and in that form i've four checkboxes and the user must check one to submit form.

this is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {   
   if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked == true) {     
       return true;
   } else {
       error += alert ("You must select atleast one previous benefit provided");
       return false
   } 
}
```

the problem is that this use return key and if i remove return key it will alert 4 times (same number of checkboxes) and if i let it be there then the if statement which check fields and give error don't work

```
if(error != "") {
   $("#error").html("<strong>Some fields are invalid!</strong>") || error;
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

if i remove return in checkbox validation then everythings work fine but it give alerts four times and if dont remove it then without giving error it submit the form.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're facing.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak what else should i provide? this is where i face problem. should i put whole validation code and html of checkboxes?

Comment: We cannot verify your problem based on the code you posted. What is `c`? What is the `error` exactly? How does the HTML looks like? Only the `checkboxes` are validated in your `form` or there are other elements for validation? Can you make working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

`alert()` doesn't return anything so your `error` logic doesn't make sense.

Create a collection of checked checkboxes and make sure it has length instead.

```
var hasChecked = $('#myForm :checkbox:checked').length;
if(!hasChecked){
    return false
    error = true;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by length? how can i do that?

Comment: Using length of jQuery object will tell you if there are selector matches or not

Comment: There is still a return key in this which is interrupting return key at the end which is taking error.

Comment: i really have no idea what that means. If you need additional help create a [mcve] demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox site